# Errorin reading a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Although my csv wasn't that large, it gave this error when i tried to read it:
`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.`
It gave this error when i used `df = pd.read_csv(path)`.
Then I changed the code into  `df = pd.read_csv(path,engine='python')`, and it perfectly worked.
What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the cause was that there were some carriage returns in the data and pandas was using as a line terminator as if it was a newline. You can try with also `lineterminator='\n'` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> sep: str, default ‘,’
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine
> cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing
> engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect
> the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In
> addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+'
> will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use
> of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to
> ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.

So you can try `df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',')` and replace the comma with whatever's used.